# Normalize a dataframe column containing JSON

Tags: json, pandas

I've got the following data set:

```
Col 1 | Col 2 | JSONBlob                                        
0     |A      |{"$type":"XYZ, X.Domain","CategoryList":"PC","ListId":"GroceryStore","FactorDescription":"Groceries",
```

The `JSONBlob` column is the only column in the dataframe that contains JSON structured data.

I'm new to Python, but I want to normalize this one column into multiple columns. There seem to be keys with associated values, ie. `"ListID": "GroceryStore"`.

I'm just not sure where to begin, I've looked at some other similar questions in StackOverflow but they generally deal with whole dataframes containing JSON, whereas I have one column.

I am importing this dataset from an excel, so I can do text to columns function in excel to prep the data, but I want to improve my Python skills

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the JSON separately then join to the original frame:

```
blobs = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    b = row['JSONBlob']
    blobs.append(pd.json_normalize(b))

blobs = pd.concat(blobs)
df = df.join(blobs)
```